# Sending an email onSave through CRM form

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm working on a CRM form right now that requires an email to be sent if a particular option is selected in an option set.  The email address is saved as a field from another form.

What is the best way to do this?  Should I be using an onSave event to trigger a javascript function?  All backend logic is .NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would use a plugin registered on an update message to send the email. If the email address was linked to a record with a lookup field, you could use a workflow.

- [CRM 2011 SDK Sample: Basic Plug-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg594416.aspx)
- [CRM 2011 Plugins : Send E-mail using Plugins](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/sv-SE/crm/thread/10ecdccb-09f7-42b7-b14b-0d7284cb7ada)
- [Sending E-mails with Dynamics CRM Workflows](http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2010/01/12/send-emails-with-workflows/)

Comment: Thanks for this.  The email address is actually stored within a field of another entity.  Would you suggest using workflows in this case?  If so, do you have any resources for accomplishing this with a workflow?

Comment: To use a workflow, the record on which it resides must be related to the base record - there is not native "search" functionality to return a record. I've updated my answer with an additional link

Comment: Additionally, emails are sent from, to, and/or cc'ed to `ActivityParty`s, which are of type `EntityReference`, not `string`. So unless your field is of type `Lookup`/`EntityReference`, it won't work.